# How users can communicate on Lync app in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, lync, rest-client

I am creating an App in window 8, based on Lync. I want that user can chat with my app through Lync server. I have got the list of contacts of a user who is login in my app. But I am not getting how he can chat with the users those are in his contact list?? I want to do this task with Rest Client.

Answer (score 0):

***ContactCard control list***
 Loads three Microsoft.Lync.Controls.ContactCard controls into a list on a page in a Silverlight or WPF application.

•WPF sample location: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\ContactCardDesktop

•Silverlight sample location: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\ContactCardSilverlight

***ContactList control***
 Populates a page with the Microsoft.Lync.Controls.ContactList control and then lists the SIP URI values for the contacts in the list.

•WPF sample location: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\ContactListDesktop

•Silverlight sample location: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\ContactListSilverlight

StartConversation 
 Uses the Automation class in the Lync Model API to start a new conversation with one Lync contact. Features include:

•Uses the Automation API in Lync to start a new conversation with new Lync contacts.

•The conversation can start with IM modalities.

Path: %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\StartConversation or %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Samples\microsamples.zip\StartConversation

The Required info is present at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933212(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933212%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I want to use Rest Clint for chatting. I am not using the Lync SDK. Can I do it with Rest Client??

Comment: How about UCWA Rest API??? Try for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/dn448474

Answer (score 0):

UCWA can be used to create Windows 8 apps. Because UCWA is essentially just HTTP request/response, it can be used anywhere that you can get an HTTP stack.

There is a working example of sending an IM using UCMWA (complete with code) at http://ucwa.lync.com/explore - check that out first. That site also has lots of information, code samples and helper libraries to get you started.

Shelby Hagman has a great post on how to set up an Conversation and send IMs, it's at http://blogs.claritycon.com/ucpractice/2013/05/14/ucwa-numbers-3-communication/